# pointer without allocating memory assignment

Tags: c, pointers

In my visual studio, this code

```
int *a, *b;
b = a;
a = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
```

Will receive a run-time check failure:variable being used without being initialized.
So if a pointer is not allocated memory then the assignment is nonsense and forbidden?
In my old opinion, a pointer is a 4 byte number in my development environment to describe a address.
So in imagination，it is this:

```
int *a, *b;
b = a;
a = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
*a = 10;
printf("%d", *b);
```

Then *b = 10; But apparently it is not that way...
**So my confused is the why pointer a and b doesn't point to the same memory in the way below?**
Can somebody explain this to me ?

Comment: Why does this work? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b5c33f1d65e47aa

Comment: @VermillionAzure Undefined behavior.

Comment: @VermillionAzure In my visual studio... I've described my environment...And what's more in your code it seems that in fact your pointer is not allocated  memory..It is used as Integer...

Comment: @Barry mmm, yes, I see.

Comment: `b = a` means: make `b` point to the memory location which `a` is currently pointing to.  It doesn't mean "make `b` an alias for `a`" or something; if you later make `a` point somewhere different then `b` has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Yeah, essentially you are assigning one uninitialized variable to another uninitialized variable.  Nothing good can come of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen an example from @Matt McNabb 
this

```
int*a, *b;
b = a;
```

doesn't mean where ever "a" is pointing, be will always point to that location after this assignment. It will do the trick only the first assignment
ie.

```
int *a, *b;
int k = 10;
int m = 20;
a = &k;
b = a; // this will point b to k
a = &m; // this will change a to point to m however b will remains pointing to k
```

Also, please note as @Barry said, you firstly have uninitialized pointer, then you assign b to point to the place where that uninitialized pointer is pointing to << this is a really bad programming habit as you will never know where a was firstly pointing to (I'm not sure if it depends on machine and compiler or not). It could cause you a big mess.

Answer (score 4):

This is bad:

```
int *a, *b;
b = a;
```

for the same reason that this is bad:

```
int a, b;
b = a;
```

You are reading an uninitialized variable. `a` has indeterminate value. It doesn't actually have to point to allocated memory, this would be fine:

```
int* a = 0;
int* b = a; // OK, a was initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

For detailed explanation,

malloc() allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.
So pointer will get new memory address assigned after successful malloc, because of which after malloc call address of a & b differs which on de-reference gives different values.

If you see output of below program, you will get your answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 1
main()
{
    int *a, *b;
    b = a;
    printf("Address of a:%p\n", a);
    printf("Address of b%p\n", b);
    a = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    printf("Address of a:%p\n", a);
    printf("Address of b%p\n", b);
    b = a; //assigning address of a to b
    *a = 10;
    printf("%d\n", *b);
}
```

Output:

```
Address of a:   0x7fff2f2813c0
Address of b:   0x7fff2f2813c0
```

After allocating memory to pointer 'a',

```
Address of a:   0x1829010
Address of b:   0x7fff2f2813c0
10
```